# Is it possible to get remote notification received time in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to get remote notification received time in ios objective c, but i don't want to use current date and time code in didReceiveRemoteNotification method. I want to get exact time of notification received from Notification object. Is it possible and how to do it? Advance Thanks for any help !

Comment: Is this a notification that the user has tapped on or a 'silent' notification?  If the former then you can put the time the notification was sent in the payload and you can get the current time when the user taps but you can't get the time that the notification was first displayed to the user. In the second case the current time on the device is basically when the notification was delivered (unless you app is terminated in which case you may never get the notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may possible do one thing:
Handle from server side add time on a key with apns and get in userinfo dict for same key.

```
like:{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"Your Message",
        "sound":"push1.wav"
     },
     "custom_key1":"value1",
     "custom_key2":"value2"
}
```